# 10.7 join 802.1x network via KDC instead of .cert?

Tags: 802.1x, kerberos

So my 10.6.8 users have to sign in to our 802.1x network with their AD creds, using previously defined local profiles using PEAP.  (I tried Login Window profiles, so that laptops would get online after signin from the loginwindow, but it wasn't reliable enough..)

The notes for 10.5 claim that Kerberos can be used (local KDC signing), but [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4772) doesn't mention Kerberos anymore.  Can 10.7 get single sign-on to 802.1x-protected networks?

Comment: Not much help for you but from what I've heard in the office and read on teh webs, kerberos is foobar in 10,7.

Comment: I suggest you ask this in one of the more technical forums of Stackexchange, such as http://superuser.com/.